# Details of Unicode Names \N Documented?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

It appears, based on a [urwid example](http://urwid.org/tutorial/#horizontal-menu) that `u'\N{HYPHEN BULLET}` will create a unicode character that is a hyphen intended for a bullet.

The names for unicode characters seem to be defined at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b.htm) and some element of using Unicode in Python appears in the [howto documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Though there is no mention of the `\N{}` syntax.

If you pull all these docs together you get the idea that the constant `u"\N{HYPHEN BULLET}"` creates a ⁃

However, this is all a theory based on pulling all this data together. I can find no documentation for `"\N{}` in the Python docs.

My question is whether my theory of operation is correct and whether it is documented anywhere?

Comment: The names are part of the [Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt), also see the duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that `u"\N{CHARACTER NAME}` produces a valid unicode character in Python.

It is not documented much in the Python docs, but after some searching I found a reference to it on effbot.org

[http://effbot.org/librarybook/ucnhash.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20200719141800/http://effbot.org/librarybook/ucnhash.htm)

> ### The ucnhash module
>
> (Implementation, 2.0 only) This module is an implementation module,
> which provides a name to character code mapping for Unicode string
> literals. If this module is present, you can use \N{} escapes to map
> Unicode character names to codes.
>
> In Python 2.1, the functionality of this module was moved to the
> **unicodedata** module.

Checking the documentation for [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) shows that the module is using the data from the Unicode Character Database.

> ### unicodedata — Unicode Database
>
> This module provides access to the Unicode Character Database (UCD)
> which defines character properties for all Unicode characters. The
> data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version
> 9.0.0.

The full data can be found at: https://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

The data has the structure: `HEXVALUE;CHARACTER NAME;etc..` so you could use this data to look up characters.

For example:

```
# 0041;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0061;
>>> u"\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}"
'A'

# FF7B;HALFWIDTH KATAKANA LETTER SA;Lo;0;L;<narrow> 30B5;;;;N;;;;;
>>> u"\N{HALFWIDTH KATAKANA LETTER SA}"
'ｻ'
```

Comment: Seems the effbot link is dead, the blog is "in pause" and its content is not accessible.

Comment: @Tshirtman - thanks. I've updated the link to point to the wayback machine.

Answer (score 6):

Not every gory detail can be found in a how-to. The [table of escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in the reference manual includes:

Escape Sequence: `\N{name}`
Meaning: Character named `name` in the Unicode database (Unicode only)

Answer (score 3):

The `\N{}` syntax is documented in the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html?highlight=unicode%20howto#the-string-type), at least.

The names are documented in the Unicode standard, such as:

```
http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt
```

The `unicodedata` module can look up a name for a character:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name('A')
'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'
>>> print('\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}')
A
```